# Nodejs, Webpack4

Tags: javascript, node.js, webpack

i want to build 1 nodejs app. I do not understand why when I build a version and copy to another place and run the node can not run because of the lack of modules.
this is file webpack:

```
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals')
const fs = require('fs')

var nodeModules = {};
fs.readdirSync('node_modules')
    .filter(function (x) {
        return ['.bin'].indexOf(x) === -1;
    })
    .forEach(function (mod) {
        nodeModules[mod] = 'commonjs ' + mod;
    });

module.exports = {
    mode: 'development',
    target: "node",
    entry: {
        server: './src/index.js',
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
        filename: '[name].js',
    },
    node: {
        __gloabal: true,
        __filename: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                exclude: '/node_modules',
                use: {
                    loader: "babel-loader"
                }
            },
            {
                test: /\.json$/,
                loader: "json"
            }
        ]
    },
    resolve: {
        extensions: [".js", ".json"],

    },
    externals: [nodeModules],
    optimization: {
        minimize: true
    }
}
```

and here when i'm running in folder before coppy:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Because you use [Externals](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/externals/) configuration option

> The externals configuration option provides a way of excluding dependencies from the output bundles. Instead, the created bundle relies on that dependency to be present in the consumer's (any end-user application) environment. This feature is typically most useful to library developers, however there are a variety of applications for it.

```js
module.exports = {
  mode: 'development',
  target: 'node',
  entry: {
    server: './src/index.js'
  },
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, 'build'),
    filename: '[name].js'
  },
  node: {
    __gloabal: true,
    __filename: true
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: '/node_modules',
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader'
        }
      },
      {
        test: /\.json$/,
        loader: 'json'
      }
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.json']
  },
  optimization: {
    minimize: true
  }
};
```

Comment: But it will err for all module i have been imported in file index.js

Comment: @NguyễnNam add index.js file on question issue